# How to get Constance to calm down in Skyrim

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

So, I killed the old lady in the orphanage pretty early like level 2, now, I'm a level 20 and Constance Michel is still frantic and running around. How do I get her to calm down? It's getting pretty upsetting. :/

Answer (score 10):

From the elder scroll wiki :

> Whether she saw the murder of Grelod or not, Constance will remain in a state of panic from Grelod's death until Innocence Lost is completed by talking to Aventus Aretino. However, she will not acknowledge the Dragonborn as the murderer once this questline is completed.

Answer (score 6):

Complete the Innocence Lost quest (by talking to Aventus in Windhelm) and she will be back to normal.

Answer (score -2):

Wait for the courier to arrive with a letter for you saying you can adopt kids, to get him to deliver it to you, simply spend some time out on the streets

Comment: Pretty sure this is only true if you have Hearthfire. As otherwise you cannot adopt. Also, according to the [wiki](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Adoption#Honorhall_Orphanage) the courier is only dispatched after the innocence lost quest is completed - meaning you must return to Aventus.